# Reading from unicode file after building the project in Java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode, xstream, diacritics

I am developing a java application in Netbeans7.4 which writes unicode German words in a XML file using XStream library and reads them again when needed using following codes:

Writing

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
{
    xstream.toXML(dataObject, writer);
    writer.close();
}
```

Reading:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
{
    dataObject = (DataObjectClass) xstream.fromXML(reader);
    reader.close();
}
```

The problem is as long as I debug the code using IDE writing and reading both work fine with unicode data, but when I build the application and run the jar file to write and read the data, application writes but cannot read the unicode data properly so it can not find them inside another text.
I cannot even debug the compiled code to see how it reads the unicode data and specially the German Umlauts (e.g. ÄäßÖöÜü) because it works fine inside IDE debug mode.

ps: The XML data file encoding is "ANSI as UTF-8".

Comment: XStream still lives? If not, maybe switch to JAXB with annotations, which is relatively easy. You can use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 which cannot throw an UnsupportedEncodingException. In NetBeans you can easily create an embedded DTD in the XML, to validate the structure. In general "ANSI as UTF-8" is a no-namer I have seen in Notepad++; it is just UTF-8 and is fine. Mind the XML better should be without BOM (special zero-width space at file begin).

Comment: Thanks, I will change my code to use JAXB and I will update the post with the results.